# Rule Selection in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page in which I want my content to be centered but, within a specific table on that page, I need to have many of the cells be left-aligned and many to be right-aligned and *one* cell to be center-aligned. Here's a snippet of HTML & CSS that should give you an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC 
   "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<style>
   .contentWrapper {
      width: 1000px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin: auto;
   }

   .centerAligned {
      text-align: center;
   }

   .myTable td {
      width: 200px;
      text-align: left;
   }

   .myTable td.label {
      text-align: right;
   }
</style>

</head>

<body>

   <div class="contentWrapper centerAligned">

      <p>A label for this table...</p>

      <table class="myTable" border="1" align="center">
         <tr>
            <td class="label">Label 1 (Right Aligned)</td>
            <td>Value 1 (Left Aligned)</td>
            <td class="label">Label 2 (Right Aligned)</td>
            <td>Value 2 (Left Aligned)</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="label">Label 3 (Right Aligned)</td>
            <td>Value 3 (Left Aligned)</td>
            <td class="label">Label 4 (Right Aligned)</td>
            <td>Value 4 (Left Aligned)</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="centerAligned">
               <input type="button" value="Push Me!">
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>

      <p>Some more content...</p>

   </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I didn't really want to put a class into every single td just to handle how they should be aligned, so I opted to set a default alignment for ".myTable td" of left. This allowed me to leave all the "value" cells to be without a class, but I still need to define one for my "label" cells to get a right alignment for those.

When it comes to the button at the bottom, which I would like to be center aligned, I want to be able to use the class "centerAligned". Unfortunately, using it here doesn't do anything as the ".myTable td" class is considered "more precise" and that cell is given a left alignment instead of a centered one.

I'm using "centerAligned" in other places, so I don't want to simply do away with that class, nor do I want to change the name to something else. I can do this:

```
.centerAligned, .myTable td.centerAligned {
   text-align: center;
}
```

That seems to work, but this whole thing seems kinda smelly to me. Is there a better way to handle styling these table cells to get the effect that I want without having to define a specific class for every single td?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `col`

Have a look here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4

Or here for XHTML
http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-xhtml2-20040722/mod-tables.html#sec_26.2.

Comment: Well there is only one problem: you can not specify text alignment on cols. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns There are only few rules that are supported by cols: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html#link3

Comment: @Ivan in XHTML 1.0 Strict `col` has an attribute `align` that can be used to set text alignment http://www.w3.org/2010/04/xhtml10-strict.html#elem_col

Comment: In practice it does not work. Here http://efekat.com/misc/col-props.html -> works only in IE7 and below.

Comment: Works fine in my world: http://jsfiddle.net/fpymF/1/ Maybe you misunderstood, I'm not referring to the `text-align` property of CSS, I'm referring to the `align` attribute of `col` **EDIT**: just noticed it does in fact **NOT** work in every popular browser. Strange..

Comment: that works in IE Bazzz, the `align` attribute is deprecated and it's CSS counterpart text-align works or doesn't just the same as the attribute - I'm afraid @Ivan Ivanić is right, the `col` element *should* be the one to use here, but it doesn't work too well cross browser :( However it can be done with CSS, if a JS solution os not desired

Comment: Agree the `col` tag SHOULD be the one, but in practice it doesn't work. It worked for me in Opera 11, just for the record. Oh `<col align="left"/>` validates in W3C's XHTML 1.0 Strict validator, so I'm not sure about it being deprecated. But it doesn't work, so it doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: Doing some necromancing ;) @clairesuzy how can it be done with CSS? Very eager to know, thanks.

Comment: have answered.. and here's the link http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/YErUw/ - it's not necessarily better, just x-browser

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use a 'th' tag for your labels and put a css on that?  That way you wont need to put a label class on all of the td 'labels'.  So

`.myTable th {
      width: 200px;
      text-align: right;
}`

Comment: this doesn't align the `td` elements in the same column

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in another answer this **should** be able to be done with `colgroup` and `col` but it can't and the `colspan` is the reason why, how would a 'colspanned' row know which `col` to take it's alignment from?

I would perhaps feel like suggesting `:nth-child` but I think it might suffer the same issue when a `colspan` was met, **and** you wouldn't get IE support so here's a fiddle which needs no classes and still uses specificity to get the desired result

#### working example based on opening code with a colspan - [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/YErUw/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery

```
$('#myTable tr td:eq(0)').css('text-align', 'left');
$('#myTable tr td:eq(1)').css('text-align', 'center');
$('#myTable tr td:eq(2)').css('text-align', 'right');
```

eq is zero based. So all first cells will be left aligned, all second cells will be center aligned and so on. Adjust to your needs.

Comment: The OP asked for a html/css solution. Surely you can use jQuery but it would create another dependency for something that can be done well with just html and css.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. I just offered a solution, it is on OP to decide whether he will go the jQuery path :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't quite describe which position the cells are that need to be right aligned vs. left aligned. But as Bazz suggested you can use col to set styles for all s in that col or maybe you can do the same with a  style if your right-aligned cells are in the same row.

If you're able to use col, all you need is:

```
<table>
 <col>
 <col class="label">
 <col>
 <tr>...
```

Then

```
.label { text-align: right }
```

There's nothing wrong with the way you're doing it though...